# CSS3 : image icon appear even if there is no image in server (Google Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome

```css
.image_main_div{
  position:relative;
  
}

.image_main_div .image_overlay_div{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    z-index:1000;
    position:absolute;
    border:thin black solid;
}

.image_main_div .image_overlay_div .image_div{
}

img{
  position: relative;
    height: 175px;
}


img:before{
  content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 175px;
    width: auto;
    background: url(https://d28hsb6vkzynsw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/No_Image.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_main_div">
  <div class="image_overlay_div">
  <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <a class="image_div">
  <img alt="" class="img-full img-responsive" height="175px" width="437px"src="https://d28hsb6vkzynsw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/no_image_upload1235.png">
  </a>
  
</div>
```

Hello,

I have a strange issue in Google Chrome.

What I do is , When there is no image in the server then the div gets default image from the server. I do that using **before** in `img`.

Now, there is no image in the div. still I get image icon and default image. and there is a border around the div.

It works fine in IE, Mozilla. but it looks like this in the Google Chrome.[image: Google Chrome Issue]

How can I solve it?

Comment: might be cache issue, press ctrl+f5 to refresh and check

Comment: I have done 3-4 times. but it is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the default behavior in Chrome. Instead, assign the fallback image in the `onerror` handler.

```html
  <img src="https://d28hsb6vkzynsw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/no_image_upload1235.png" 
onerror="this.src='https://d28hsb6vkzynsw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/No_Image.png'">
```

Comment: thank you for that. just one thing. can't i do it using css? as though it is default image but still it will take time to load into html from the server. so is it possible using only css that works fine in all browsers?

Comment: @Rishi You can hide the img in the onerror handler. But for that, you have to put background image in another thing, not img:before. Maybe you can put it on img itself and set src to just empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It's come from direct server see remove it

```
https://d28hsb6vkzynsw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/no_image_upload1235.png
```

```css
.image_main_div{
  position:relative;
  
}

.image_main_div .image_overlay_div{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    z-index:1000;
    position:absolute;
  border:0px;
}

.image_main_div .image_overlay_div .image_div{
}

img{
  position: relative;
    height: 175px;
}


img:before{
  content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 175px;
    width: auto;
    background: url();
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center center;
background: url(https://d28hsb6vkzynsw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/No_Image.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="image_main_div">
  <div class="image_overlay_div">
  <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <a class="image_div">
  <img alt="" class="img-full img-responsive" height="175px" width="437px"src="">
  </a>
  
</div>
```

Comment: then there should be default image appeared as i have used **img:before** and also there is a border behind black transparent background. How it could come?

Comment: Actually you had given pics in both section like in `css` & `html` so i have removed from `html` but in `img:before` pics is available that is showing as default pic check now my answer again. I update my answer

Comment: also there is a border behind layer. so how can i remove it?

Comment: Border come because of you had given `height="175px" width="437px"` inside image tag but there is blank  ` src=""` remove that and check